# Adding MySQL Trigger: invisible (to me) Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

**NOTE:
 I *initially* thought my problem had to do with `CONCAT`, but since the exact error persisted even when I *completely* eliminated `CONCAT` from my query, I figured I should completely over-write of my original post.**

I'm trying to set a trigger, and keep getting a Syntax Error.
When I tried this

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_aka_name 
BEFORE INSERT ON sandbox_person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.aka IS NULL) THEN
    SET NEW.aka = 'test value';
  END IF;
END
```

...I got this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

And when trying *this* (without the `IF` peren's)

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_aka_name 
BEFORE INSERT ON sandbox_person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.aka IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.aka = 'test value';
  END IF;
END
```

...I get the ***same exact*** error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

It's *got* to be something simple ... but I'm just not seeing it.
I'm on MySQL 5.1.36.
What am I missing?
Any pointers?

Comment: I'd guess you forgot to use `DELIMITER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change delimiter first:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER set_aka_name 
BEFORE INSERT ON sandbox_person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.aka IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.aka = 'test value';
  END IF;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Maybe MySQL sees the first ";" as the end of CREATE TRIGGER

Comment: **FANTASTIC !!** That created the trigger, thanks! ... but ... the trigger's not working ?:( ... This was the answer to _this_ question though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_aka_name 
BEFORE INSERT ON sandbox_person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.aka IS NULL THEN
    NEW.aka = CONCAT(NEW.fname, ' ', NEW.lname);
  END IF;
END
```

there is a difference between `IF ()` *function* and `IF` *statement* ([see this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html))

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) ... but ... the error still persists (except the error references line 6 now rather than line 5). Any other thoughts??

Comment: do you have enough privileges? especially TRIGGER or SUPER privilege?
try to add DEFINER sentence:

    CREATE DEFINER =  `user`@`database` TRIGGER `set_aka_name

Comment: Sufficient privileges have now been confirmed . Any other thoughts? ... BTW, please notice the updated question.