# How to two Column in another column using SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two column in my database like:

```
Fisrt Name    |     Last Name    |    Full Name
------------------------------------------------
 Fayyaz       |       Jaan       |
 Danny        |       Rock       |
 Tom          |       Jerry      |
```

I have another column "Full Name" that is empty and I want to merge these two column in the third column like"

```
Fisrt Name    |     Last Name    |    Full Name
----------------------------------------------------
 Fayyaz       |       Jaan       |    Fayyaz Jaan
 Danny        |       Rock       |    Danny Rock 
 Tom          |       Jerry      |    Tom Jerry
```

Any helpfor SQL query.
Thanks

Hi everyone I found the right notation of concatination of two columns within the query

```
UPDATE contact SET fullName=CONCAT(firstName,LastName)
```

But the problem is, the resulted column has no space between the first and last name. like "TomJerry" and "DannyRock" 
Any help?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, something else?

Comment: Next time, please include the DB you're using. Stuff like this is very DB dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work:

```
UPDATE <table> SET FullName = FirstName || ' ' || LastName
```

Or, seeing your edit, this will probably work:

```
UPDATE <table> SET FullName = CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName);
```

And, if that doesn't work, then this will:

```
UPDATE <table> SET FullName = CONCAT(CONCAT(FirstName,' '),LastName);
```

Comment: this query also generating all 0s in the column. I don't know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
update <table> set FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName
```

Otherwise, add the 3rd result to select, something like

```
select firstname, lastname, firstname + ' ' + lastname as FullName from <table>
```

Comment: I have copied your query but the column initialize with 0. and i have phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your DBMS, you can just use a computed column (SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   firstName varchar(30),
   lastName varchar(30),
   fullName AS firstName + ' ' + lastName
);
```

If using MySQL, you can [use a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360493/679449) to do this automatically or to manually concatenate the columns:

```
UPDATE tableName SET fullName = CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)
```

Comment: I am using MYSQL that support only CONCAT function for concatenation but it does not add space in between the value like "FayyazJaan" there should be space between two names. Thanks

Comment: Another option is to use MariaDB which has implemented computed columns.